# internet connection and ubuntu shutdown

Tags: wireless

I was having trouble connecting to the internet,so I proceeded to connect directly via a cable. Then, after I connected to the internet, I installed Ubuntu One and Chromium and attempted to install the Broadcom wireless driver which was then activated. As I proceeded to restart, chaos began. My screen is freezing and my computer does not start properly anymore. I have been to 12.0 4.5 on Windows 7 on a Dell Inspiron 6400.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the order of my tasks, you will see that I installed the Broadcom wireless driver last. After a re-install, I found that I needed to install the Broadcom wireless driver first, plus any and all updates relevant to 12.04.5 Lts version. Be careful when you update because several of the updates are for version 14.

Again, this was for a first time installation of Ubuntu and running a dual boot.